# Composer autoload not found classes psr4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I try to use composer to load custom classes which are located in specific folder.

Here is my project strucure

```
public
|—index.php
src
|—classes
    |— MyClass
          |— MyClass.php
vendor
|—autoload.php
composer.json
```

Index.php

```
<?php

namespace ink;

require ( vendor/autoload.php );

use ink\src\classes\MyClass\MyClass;

$customclasse = new MyClass();
```

MyClass.php

```
<?php

namespace ink\src\classes\MyClass;

class MyClass {

     public function __construct(){
     }
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    autoload : {
        psr-4 : {
            ink\\ : src 
        }
    }
}
```

What I’m doing wrong ?
Namespaces seems good cause when I require MyClass.php everything works fine, class is loaded.

Thanks

Comment: what is the error you get ?

Comment: Class MyClass not found

Comment: did you generate the autoload.php ?

Comment: I did using composer install, update, dump-autoload too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doubling up a `src` level.

By `ink\\ : src` you are saying that anything after `ink` is in the `src` folder.

But your class is in a `ink\src\classes\MyClass` namespaces.

So this adds up to `src`+`src/classes/MyClass`=`src/src/classes/MyClass` path.

So you likely need:

```
{
    autoload : {
        psr-4 : {
            ink\\src\\ : src 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it seems you are not respecting the PSR-4 specification.

As per the specification says :

> A fully qualified class name has the following form :
>
> **\NamespaceName(\SubNamespaceNames)*\ClassName**

Folder structure

```
├── composer.json
├── public
│   └── index.php
├── src
│   └── Classes
│       └── Models
│           └── MyClass.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    └── composer
        ├── autoload_classmap.php
        ├── autoload_namespaces.php
        ├── autoload_psr4.php
        ├── autoload_real.php
        ├── ClassLoader.php
        └── LICENSE
```

index.php

```
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Ink\Classes\Models\MyClass;

$customclasse = new MyClass();

?>
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "app",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Ink\\": "src/" }
    }
}
```

MyClass.php

```
<?php 

namespace Ink\Classes\Models;

class MyClass {

     public function __construct(){
     }
}
```